# How do I eliminate FOUC with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

So when I navigate around my app at (https://notes-noted.herokuapp.com) i see flashes of unstyled CSS. I am linking to the stylesheets in the head of the application file. My head section looks like this:

```
!!!
%html
%head
%title Noted | Online Notebook Application
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks- track' => true
= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
%link{:rel => "stylesheet", :href =>  "//opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.6.1/font-awesome.min.css"}/
= csrf_meta_tags
%style
    type="text/css"
    .fouc { display:none; }
%script
    type="text/javascript"
    try {
    var html=document.getElementByName("html");
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { html.class=""; });
    html.class="fouc";
    }
    catch() {
    }
```

Can anyone recommend any solutions other to the coding I have tried here?

Comment: not sure if typo but your data-turbolinks-track has a whitespace in there

Comment: Hi, i was trying to write out in code and may have added that by mistake. Not sure why it renders the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your HAML. You are rendering your styles and js wrongly.

```
%style
    type="text/css"
    .fouc { display:none; }
%script
    type="text/javascript"
```

This should be:

```
:css
    .fouc { display:none; }
:javascript
    try {
        var html=document.getElementByName("html");
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { html.class=""; });
        html.class="fouc";
    } catch() {}
```

Comment: I have altered the code but the site still seems to show unstyled text in safari and chrome. Is it the same for you?

https://blooming-savannah-84310.herokuapp.com

Comment: @Sapsford11, sorry I missed some js code while doing copy/paste. Updated my answer. Regarding your site fonts. No, they look ok in chrome & safari. I am on OSX.

Comment: With the new code in i think i have solved the issue apart from one thing. When i go from the home page to log in and use the browser back button, i get a twitchy loading response. The new url is at https://notes-noted.herokuapp.com

Comment: `No such app` error on your original URL. The twitching seems to be related to `turbolinks` or a javascript error on in your `application.js`. You can see in browser console that there are several ajax requests fired that cause twitching. I assumed it is because of the turbolinks. But, I might be wrong. See your console in development environment.